# Using Merge Sort to sort an array of objects by one of its properties?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, object, merge

Just incase the title isn't clear. I would like to be able to sort an array of objects based on ONE of its properties (say sort the prices of the items from lowest to highest).

What I've managed to do, is:

```
double[] newArray = new double[Obj.Length];
while loop{
newArray[ctr] = Obj[ctr].price
}
```

This means that the newArray has the PRICE property of the object array. I'm able to sort this no problem.

But, I don't understand how I'm able to adapt the Merge sort algorithm (please note I **have to use merge sort here, and not some built in Array.Sort function**). This is because merge sort is recursive, so using the object array as a parameter, in my mind doesn't seem viable.

I do hope this makes sense, if it needs any clarification I will edit.

Comment: I think **Uni Homework** more accurately describes the merge sort requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible options are:

1. If you're given the property name as a string then assuming that the property to compare is of a type implementing the [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface then you use a reflection to extract the property values from the objects to be compared.
2. Alternatively you can have mergesort accept a delegate for the comparison logic (e.g. `int Compare(obj x, obj y)`, or [`Func<T, T, TRes>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647(v=vs.110).aspx)) and use this delegate for comparing the objects.